# Debugging using PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, xdebug

I used Xdebug for debugging in PHP v7. The way I did that its not working for PHP version 5.3.8.

From the https://xdebug.org/wizard.php page, when I paste `phpinfo()` text it shows error:

> The compiler (MS VC9) that this PHP was build with, is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a version that was built with MS VC11 or MS VC14.

How to debug using PHP v5.3.8

Comment: You are going to need to install XDebug 2.2.7. Its on the [XDEBUG download page](https://xdebug.org/download.php)

Comment: You will also need an Apache that was compiled with VC9 but I assume you have that if PHP5.3 is running on your server/localhost

Comment: There is probably a good reason you still run php 5.3, but please note that it has been EOL for ages now. Try to update to at least 5.6 and preferably 7.1 or 7.2 if you have the possibility

Answer (score 4):

Download an older version for the matching PHP version: https://xdebug.org/download.php.

They may not be *supported* anymore, but old versions continue to work as they did when they were still actively supported.